# Getting java.security.cert.CertificateException while using Amazon Corretto

Tags: java, corretto

I used the following code in Oracle Java 1.8, it was working fine. But replacing Oracle Java with Amazon Corretto 8 I get this error:

Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching xxxxxx:636 not found.

Below is the code :

```
final String ldapAdServer = "ldaps://xxxxxx:636";
final String ldapSearchBase = "ou=people,o=xxxx.com";

Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=xxxx,ou=Apps,o=xxxx.com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "xxxxx");
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapAdServer);

DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

Comment: Hi, see if this helps you. https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues/273

Comment: I also notice that in Corretto 15 as known issue there's something similar. The certificate_authorities extension, when enabled with -Djdk.tls.client.enableCAExtension=true, may not work with the default keystore provided with Corretto 15. If you would like to use this functionality, we recommend you provide a custom keystore.